# Unity Google Android Project option missing

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I wanted to export the Unity Project I am creating into Android Studio. I googled for possible solutions and I saw this "Google Android Project" option in Unity but I can't see the option anywhere and do not know how will I be able to see it. I have **Unity 5.5.1f1** Personal currently installed on my computer.

Here's how my Build option looks like:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Google Android Project*  option has been removed. It's now called *ADT(Legacy)*. There is also *Gradle(New)*. They can both generate Unity Project for you.

*Internal (Default)* will use the Unity's built-in build system to build the project and generate apk file for Android.

Gradle (New) will generate *Google Android Project* **with** gradle files.

*ADT (Legacy)* will generate *Google Android Project* **without** gradle files like it used to do before.  This behaves like the old *Google Android Project* option.

[image]